# Adding events to menu options

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

//ActionScript code

> import mx.controls.Menu;
>              import flash.events.MouseEvent;
>
> ```
>         private var menu12:Menu;
>
>         private function init():void {
>             menu12 = new Menu();
>             menu12.labelField = "@label";
>             menu12.dataProvider = xmlDP;
>             menu12.showRoot = false;
>             menu12.width = popUpButton.width;
>             popUpButton.popUp = menu12;
>         }
> ```

// XML Info

```
        <menu1 label="Some introduction" />
        <menu2 label="Disabled State (disabled)." enabled="false" />
        <sep1 type="separator" />
        <menu3 label="parent">
            <menu4 label="child1" />
        </menu3>
        <menu5 label="parent (disabled)" enabled="false">
            <menu6 label="child1" />
            <menu7 label="child2" />
            <menu8 label="child3" />
        </menu5>
        <menu9 type="separator" />
        <menu10 type="separator" />
        <menu11 id="leftButton" label="Left" type="radio" groupName="radioGroup" toggled="true" enabled="true"  />
        <menu12 id="rightButton" label="Right" type="radio" groupName="radioGroup" enabled="false" />
        <menu13 id="popupButton" label="Popup" type="radio" groupName="radioGroup" enabled="false" />

    </root>
```

// component

```
<mx:PopUpButton id="popUpButton"
            label="Please select an item"
            openAlways="true"
            creationComplete="init();" />
```

how to add addevents to the menus in the popupButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it....

Add an attribute to each of the XML items to store an Event name for each Menu Item:

```
<menu4 label="child1" eventName="child1Event" />
```

And add an Event Listener for each known Event when the parent component is initialized:

```
private function init():void
{
    menu12 = new Menu();
    ...

    addEventListener("child1Event", child1EventHandler);
}

private function child1EventHandler(event:Event):void
{
    ....
}
```

(You could even parse the XML to add the event listeners dynamically

```
private function init():void
{
    menu12 = new Menu();
    ...

    addEventListener("child1Event", 
        function(event:Event)
        {
            alert(event.type);
        }
        );
}
```

Add an itemClick Event Handler:

```
private function popUpButton_itemClickHandler(event:MenuEvent):void
{
    if (event.item.@eventName != null)
        dispatchEvent(new Event(event.item.@eventName));
}

<mx:PopUpButton id="popUpButton"
        label="Please select an item"
        openAlways="true"
        creationComplete="init();" 
        itemClick="popUpButton_itemClickHandler(event);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

`menu12.addEventListener(MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK,itemClickHandler);`

at the end of your init function then add the listener function

`private function itemClickHandler(event:MenuEvent):void{}`

to your script.

Comment: `menu12.addEventListener(MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK,itemClickHandler);` - This is for the menu, but i want to add to the nodes of each XML. for instance if i want to add an event for a particular node in xml... how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put an event handler on a specific XML node the way you want. You'll have to look at the event coming in to be able to tell which handler should run. Take a look at Theo Hultberg's concept of guards to make the filtering code cleaner:

http://blog.iconara.net/2008/03/30/separating-event-handling-from-event-filtering/